# Split column of list of names into all combinations of initials

Tags: pandas, dataframe, split, names

I have a dataframe with a column "First names" e.g. John Richard.
I want to look for all 4 combinations of name + initial and store it in a seperate column. So in this case I would want to return [(J R, John R, J Richard, John Richard)]. I know I could write a for loop and loop over each element of the list, but is there a faster/more efficient way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, python has efficient `itertools` implementation:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

df = pd.DataFrame([['John Richard'],['John Fitz Kennedy']],columns=['name'])

def cart_prod(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)): lst[i] = [lst[i],lst[i][0]]
    return [" ".join(i) for i in product(*lst)]

df['new_names'] = df.name.str.split().apply(cart_prod)
df
```